# MySQL CPU Usage Surge up When Multiple Post Editor Pages are open

Tags: wp-admin, mysql

I am managing WordPress server 2Core CPU 8Gb Ram, hosted on Openlitespeed + MariaDB 11.4, PHP 7.4. Redis and OPache are installed. On the WordPress site, [Redis Object Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redis-cache/) and [Litespeed LSCache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/litespeed-cache/) are plugins installed and enabled.

Memory Limit: 512MB,
Max Execution time: 120

The site has over 140k posts, browsing the site pages and content is a smooth experience.

But the problem is whenever the editor login to create a post, the CPU usage surge to 90% or more. and the wp-admin/post-new.php become as slows as a snail, sometimes I could take more than minutes before it gets ready, sometimes crashed that publish button will be greyed-out. It gets worse when they open multiple instances of wp-admin/post-new.php.

[image]

I have tried to disable all plugins, change the theme with the plugin disabled, it doesn't fix.

It only gets a little bit better if I disable Classic Editor, using the default Gutenberg editor.

## My Test and Findings

When I install [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) I discovered that a query is running slow taking up to 25 seconds to complete, on other tabs or instances of **wp-admin/post-new.php** it could read up to 100 seconds, some case makes the site stop responding.

```
SELECT DISTINCT meta_key 
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key NOT BETWEEN '_'
AND '_z'
HAVING meta_key NOT LIKE '\\_%'
ORDER BY meta_key LIMIT 30
```

[image]

I thought Installing Redis on the VPS and the Redis Cache Object would give a better performance. This could be true as other parts of the website are fast loading except for the post editor page where the query above is running.

Presently, I have disabled the classic editor, but the user (editors) preferred it. Please what do I need to do more to optimise the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching the web over the night I found out that the problem is common and the same query I posted above is the culprit. According to [WordPress Post Editor Performance](https://9seeds.com/wordpress-admin-post-editor-performance/), this is caused by **Slow meta_form() database query**

The safest solution he provided was a piece of code the function.php. I did that and I experience a great deal of changed. see code below:

```
/**
 * Remove Ancient Custom Fields metabox from post editor
 * because it uses a very slow query meta_key sort query
 * so on sites with large postmeta tables it is super slow
 * and is rarely useful anymore on any site
 */
function wpse391530_remove_post_custom_fields_metabox() {
     foreach ( get_post_types( '', 'names' ) as $post_type ) {
         remove_meta_box( 'postcustom' , $post_type , 'normal' );   
     }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'wpse391530_remove_post_custom_fields_metabox' );
```

You can read more about the solution on the article link posted above

Comment: please why you have changed the original code "s9" with 'wpse391530' ??? i see in the site you post it that this code wil not work with gutenberg editor.

Comment: wpse391530 is derived from WordPress Stack Exchange and the question ID 391530